# Pyrocms avoids 0 when tags are used

Tags: tags, pyrocms

I am fetching results with query and using plugin and tags to display data on a page built by Control Panel. I need to display the total view count of each product. By default it is 0. the wierd thing if the count is greater than 0 it displays all right but if there is no view count means if count is 0 it does not display anything. I have tried conditions but they are also not working. How can i dispay 0 fetched from query using tags?

EDITED :

Here is what i am trying to do.
This is the query

```
SELECT 
    ldc.id,
    ldc.product_name,
    ldc.product_viewed,
FROM default_products AS ldc
```

Here product_viewed is an integer field which contain the number of views by users. The default value for a new product is 0 (uploaded by admin).

This is tag i am using to display product_viewed

```
<table>
{{ Products:getProductsDetail }}
    <tr>
        <td>Product Name</td>
        <td><h2>{{ product_name }}</h2></td>
        <td>Hits</td>
        <td>{{ product_viewed }}</td>
    </tr>
{{ /Products:getProductsDetail }}
</table>
```

Everything is working fine except the {{ product_viewed }} because it contains 0. I have tested the query and its working fine fetching the results as expected but using Lex Parser tag it displays nothing. I have simplified my query here is image result

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/138/testmy.png/

You can see Hits : display nothing . This is what i am facing.

Comment: When you're talking about code, why not post the code? A pastie is worth a million words.

Comment: @Phil Sturgeon Thanks for your reply i have updated my question. Please take a look.

Comment: Which version of PyroCMS are you using? This sounds like a bug that was fixed in 2.1.4 or 2.1.5.

Comment: thanks Phil i am using old version there having problem with this. I will upgrade to the latest one now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I am using old version. Using latest version does not encounter this problem.